# try/catch and inputmismatchexception

Tags: java, try-catch

why do I need to import inputmismatchexception when I try

```
catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("cant print");
```

but when I try the following, I don't have to import anything?

```
catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("cant print");
```

Comment: Because the class InputMismatchException is not initially imported while AirthmeticException is. The same reason, why you can use `System.out.println` but not `Math.sqrt` without import.

Comment: Arithmetic exception is from java.lang package which is the default package you no need to import. InputMismatchexception is from java.util package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why do I need to import inputmismatchexception

`java.util.InputMismatchException` is in `java.uti` package. You should import it Since its not imported by default.

[java.util.InputMismatchException doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)

> I don't have to import anything?

`java.lang.ArithmeticException` is in `java.lang` package. You no need of importing this package Since its imported by default.

[java.lang.ArithmeticException doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html)

`java.lang` have the core java language classes.

[See java.lang doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html)